# Inserting data from local infile into MySQL. Changed local_infile but still getting error

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'm trying to insert data into a MySQL table from a CSV file.  Here is the query I'm working with

```
use classicmodels;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\code\\datasources\\customer.csv'  INTO TABLE customers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(customerNumber, customerName, contactLastName, contactFirstName, phone, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, postalCode, country, salesRepEmployeeNumber, creditLimit, customerLocation)
```

When I execute it, I am given an error :

> Error Code: 3948. Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides.

From my research, the fix looked like I just needed to execute this command

```
SET @@GLOBAL.`local_infile` := 1;
```

I did that and verified that `local_infile` changed from `0` to `1`, however I'm still getting that same error message. Does anybody have a fix for this?

I'm using MySQL 8.0.19.

Comment: Have You followed [this article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html) ?

Comment: That is pretty confusing

Answer (score 1):

The error messages tells you to make sure that 1.

1. Enable loading file on server-side
2. Enable loading file on client-side

You enable loading from file server-side by doing:

`SET @@GLOBAL.`local_infile`:= 1;`

But you also have to make enable it in your client. To do so invoke the client with the option `--local-infile=1`

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html